# Ubuntu 10.10 MySQL

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I have installed MySQL on my Ubuntu Server 10.10, all fine, database is running, I can login via mysql -uroot -ppassword or via mysql administrator from another cmoputer etc.

But

When I do :
    `chkconfig mysql --list`
    `mysql        0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off`

```
chkconfig mysql --list  
mysql off
```

If I do :

```
service mysql status  
mysql start/running, process 665
```

I am confused as I thought chkconfig would be used to see what is running at what run levels and it is showing mysql as off.

Also, when I checked the run-level by `who -r` it was showing as `runlevel 2` (Ubuntu Server 10.10), i had to do a `init 3` and then it displayed run-level 3

Any suggestions would be helpful
Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in more recent versions of Ubuntu many init scripts have been converted into "upstart" jobs. As far as I know, chkconfig only checks the symlinks for the older-style `/etc/rc*.d` directories. Meanwhile, many packages (including MySQL) have converted their init scripts to upstart jobs.

To find out more about MySQL's upstart job, such as what runlevels it starts on, `cat /etc/init/mysql.conf`

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for your prompt reply, How can One check all services which are running in that session via command line ? 
when you say upstart jobs, does the syntax to start / stop or check service level is `upstart servicename status` ?
any link to ubuntu services would be helpful. Kind regards

Comment: Upstart's syntax to find out the status is like: `sudo status mysql.` If it's running, you will see something like `mysql start/running, process 9475`. To stop the service, `sudo stop mysql` will do. And to start, `sudo start mysql`